# Recursively retrieving neighbors in a quadtree

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, collision-detection, quadtree

I'm working on a simple quadtree implementation for doing collision detection of circles.  Right now the logic for insertion is:

1) Check if the node has subtrees.

2) If it has subtrees, determine which subtree the children should be appended to by using `_get_index()`.  If it returns -1, then the child is appended to the parent node.

3) If the node has no subtrees, append the child to the parent node.

For retrieval, I should only retrieve children of parent nodes I run into as I traverse the tree, as well as the final leaf node.

The logic being:

1) Place the children of the parent node into the list.

2) Check the index of the target that I want to find the neighbors of.

3) Call `retrieve_neighbors()` on that node to recursively.

However, when I run the code, I find that I am always returning *every* object in the tree with `retrieve_neighbors()`, thus defeating the point of storing everything in a quadtree.

The first issue that might come to mind is if when I `split()` the nodes, the children aren't erased, so each child is also in the parent node -- however, just by counting the number of children in the tree, there doesn't seem to be an redundancy.

The code is below:

```
class Quadtree(object):
    """
    A simple Quadtree implementation.  This works with any child object that has a get_position() method that returns a list
    or tuple.
    """

    def __init__(self, depth, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y):
        self.depth = depth
        self.max_depth = 8
        self.min_x = min_x
        self.max_x = max_x
        self.mid_x = (max_x - min_x) / 2.0
        self.min_y = min_y
        self.max_y = max_y
        self.mid_y = (max_y - min_y) / 2.0
        self.has_children = False
        self.max_children = 4
        self.children = []
        self.subtrees = []

    def _get_index(self, child):
        """
        Returns the index of the node that the object belongs to.  Returns -1 if the object does not exist in the tree.
        """
        index = -1
        child_position = child.get_position()
        child_radius = child.get_radius()
        if len(child_position) != 2:
            print "Quadtree is only designed to handle two-dimensional objects! Object will not be added."
            return index
        #check if it fits in the top or bottom
        is_in_top_quadrant = child_position[1] - child_radius > self.mid_y and child_position[1] + child_radius < self.max_y
        #check if it fits left
        if child_position[0] + child_radius < self.mid_x and child_position[0] - child_radius > self.min_x:
            if is_in_top_quadrant:
                index = 1
            else:
                index = 2
        #check if it fits right
        if child_position[0] - child_radius > self.mid_x and child_position[0] + child_radius < self.mid_x:
            if is_in_top_quadrant:
                index = 0
            else:
                index = 3
        return index

    def insert(self, new_child):
        """
        Insert an object into the tree.  Returns True if the insert was successful, False otherwise.
        """
        index = self._get_index(new_child)
        if index != -1 and self.subtrees:
            self.subtrees[index].insert(new_child)
            return True
        else:
            #if no subtrees exist, add the child to the child list.
            self.children.append(new_child)

        #and then check if we need to split the tree
        #if there are more than the max children, and we haven't maxed out the tree depth, and there are no subtrees yet
        if len(self.children) > self.max_children and self.depth < self.max_depth and not self.subtrees:
            #create new subtree lists
            self.split()
            #iterate over all chidren in this node
            for child in self.children:
                index = self._get_index(child)
                if index != -1:
                    self.children.remove(child)
                    self.subtrees[index].insert(child)

        return True

    def retrieve_neighbors(self, child):
        """
        Retrieve all children from the same leaf as the target child.
        """
        index = self._get_index(child)
        neighbors = []
        neighbors += self.children

        if self.subtrees and index != -1:
            neighbors += self.subtrees[index].retrieve_neighbors(child)

        return neighbors

    def split(self):
        """
        Split the trees into four subtrees.
        """
        #top right
        self.subtrees.append(Quadtree(self.depth + 1, self.mid_x, self.mid_y, self.max_x, self.max_y))
        #top left
        self.subtrees.append(Quadtree(self.depth + 1, self.min_x, self.mid_y, self.mid_x, self.max_y))
        #bottom left
        self.subtrees.append(Quadtree(self.depth + 1, self.min_x, self.min_y, self.mid_x, self.mid_y))
        #bottom right
        self.subtrees.append(Quadtree(self.depth + 1, self.mid_x, self.min_y, self.max_x, self.mid_y))
```

Can anyone help me figure out why my quadtree is returning too many children?

thanks!

Comment: Upon further investigation, there may be some issues with how items are inserted -- it seems that items always go into the third branch (index of 2), regardless of the depth of tree.